# I cant seem to find why this code doesn`t work

Tags: php, mysql, forms, while-loop, session-variables

### DISCLAIMER THIS IS A SCHOOL PROJECT, SO MYSQL IS OK TO USE.

So, i wanted to make use of some post method forms. I wrote and rewrote this code 3 times now. But it does not seem to send the post values well...into post...also, i want that once one form is selected to dissapear ( in order not to confuse the user). I managed to do that in another version using the `or, ||` operator but in this version I dont use it iin order to keep things simple.

Here is the code

```
$clasa_elevului = $_SESSION['clasa'];
$scoala_elevului = $_SESSION['scoala'];
$judetul_elevului = $_SESSION['judet'];



?>
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?ex=8"> ALEGE ALT ELEV! </a><br />
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit93']))
{

    $_SESSION['elevi'] = $_POST['elevi'];
}


else //daca nu am apasat butonul de alegere a elevului
{
$alegeelevul = "SELECT cod_elev, prenume_elev
FROM elevi
WHERE id_clasa = $clasa_elevului AND id_scoala = $scoala_elevului AND id_judet = $judetul_elevului
ORDER BY cod_elev";
$elevul = mysql_query($alegeelevul);
?>
Alege elevul:

<form method="post" action="" name="form40">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>

    <td  width="150"><select name="scoala">
<option value="">Alege elevul</option>
   <?php
 while($elevii = mysql_fetch_array($elevul))
{

      echo "<option value='".$elevii['cod_elev']."' name='elevi'>" . $elevii['prenume_elev'] . "</option>";

  }
  ?>
  </select>
  </td></tr>

  </table> <br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit93" value="&nbsp;Alege &nbsp;" >
     </form>


   <?php 
   }  

   /* PANA AICI TINE ELSE DACA NU AM APASAT BUTONUL DE TRIMITERE. DE AICI IN JOS ESTE MATERIA !!! DE AICI IN SUS E ELEVUL!!!!  */
   ?>  

  <?php if(isset($_POST['submit10']))//daca e apasat butonul submit 10
  {
      $_SESSION['materii'] = $_POST['materii'];
  }

  else
  {
      ?>

    Acum alege materia :
<?php
$alege_materia = "SELECT
  dmedia_didact.materii.id AS id,
  dmedia_didact.materii.materie
FROM
  dmedia_didact.materii INNER JOIN
  dmedia_didact.materii_pe_clase ON dmedia_didact.materii_pe_clase.id_materie =
    dmedia_didact.materii.id
    WHERE dmedia_didact.materii_pe_clase.`id_clasa` = $clasa_elevului AND dmedia_didact.materii_pe_clase.`id_scoala` = $scoala_elevului ";
    $materia = mysql_query($alege_materia);
?>
<form method="post" action="" name="form60">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>

    <td  width="150"><select name="scoala">
<option value="">Alege materia</option>
   <?php
 while($materii = mysql_fetch_array($materia))
{

      echo "<option value='".$materii['id']."' name='materii'>" . $materii['materie'] . "</option>";

  }
  ?>
  </select>
  </td></tr>

  </table> <br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit10" value="&nbsp;Alege &nbsp;" >
     </form><br />
<?php
  } //sfarsit else daca NU am apasat submit 10 
if(isset($_SESSION['elevi']))
{
echo $_SESSION['elevi'];    
}
```

Please note that the first 3  session variables are working ok. The forms show the database contents for them.

What is wrong with it? Thank you!

EDIT: the errors look like this: `Notice: Undefined index: materii in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 620`

line 620 is this one:

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['submit10']))//daca e apasat butonul submit 10
  {
      ***$_SESSION['materii'] = $_POST['materii'];***
  }
```

**FOOLISH ME!!! I RESOLVED THE PROBLEM BY LOOKING AT THE CODE HERE. THE PROBLEM IS I DID NOT USE THE SELECT NAME TAG IN THE POST, BUT I USED THE OPTION NAME TAG. NOW IT IS WORKING!**

Comment: This happens to me all the time. I formulate a question for everyone, and in the process of doing so, the answer becomes apparent. Well done.

Comment: Thank you all! It happens to me all the time to post a question, and while reading it to understand the problem:) The best community website ever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how `<select>` is working.

Assuming you have

```
<select name="nameOfTheSelect">
<option value="x">sample value</option>
<option value="y">another value</option>
</select>
```

and the user selects the second value (another value) and post it, you will recieve it as:

```
$_POST['nameOfTheSelect'] == 'y';
```

So, the `<option>` does not have it's own name, because it's a value. You do not have `$_POST['y']`here (in your case `$_POST['materili']`

Comment: I choose your question as an accepted answer, even though I already had resolved the problem ( as stated in the question before you answered) because you explained it very well, and if someone other has this problem, they would be able to understand it better from your answer than from my added details :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following:

```
<select name="scoala">
<option value="">Alege elevul</option>
   <?php
 while($elevii = mysql_fetch_array($elevul))
{    
      echo "<option value='".$elevii['cod_elev']."' name='elevi'>" . $elevii['prenume_elev'] . "</option>";

  }
  ?>
  </select>
```

To

```
<select name="elivi">
<option value="">Alege elevul</option>
   <?php
 while($elevii = mysql_fetch_array($elevul))
{

      echo "<option value='".$elevii['cod_elev'].">" . $elevii['prenume_elev'] . "</option>";

  }
  ?>
  </select>
```

You cannot have a `name` attribute on an `<option>`. `name` should go in the `<select>`.